# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'User.User' that has not been installed

Tags: python, django

I wanna use my custom user in my Django project and I wanna use the OTP system for login in my project so I deleted the username and password field of the user and the user should login with a phone number. But I am getting an error.

These are my codes:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, phone_number):
    user = self.model(
        phone_number = phone_number
    )
    if not phone_number:
        raise ValueError('Phone number is required')
    user.save(using = self._db)
    user.is_superuser = False
    user.is_admin = False
    user.name = "green user"
    return user

def create_superuser(self, phone_number):
    user = self.create_user(
        phone_number = phone_number
    )
    user.is_superuser = True

class User(AbstractUser):
username            = None
password            = None
email               = models.EmailField(null = True, blank = True)
is_superuser        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_admin            = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_active           = models.BooleanField(default=True)
phone_number        = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
is_owner            = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_advisor          = models.BooleanField(default=False)
name                = models.CharField(max_length=40)
image               = models.ImageField(blank = True, null=True)
data_join           = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
code_agency         = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['phone_number',]

objects = UserManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.phone_number

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
model = User
list_display = ('phone_number', 
                'email')
list_filter = ('phone_number',
                'email')
search_fields = ('phone_number') 
ordering = ('phone_number')  
filter_horizontal = ()
fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (
        (None, {'fields': ('phone_number',)}),
)
```

In my setting I set `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'User.User'`

and this is my admin.py:

`admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)`

But I get an error in the terminal:

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'User.User' that has not been installed`

Comment: what is your app name in which you created this `User` model...??

Comment: User is my appname

Comment: have you added `User` app in `INSTALLED_APPS`...??

Comment: yes of course..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your models.py:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class UserCustomManager(BaseUserManager):

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, phone_number, password, **extra_fields):
        if not phone_number:
            raise ValueError('The given phonenumber must be set')
        user = self.model(phone_number=phone_number, username=phone_number, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, phone_number, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(phone_number, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, phone_number, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(phone_number, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    # You have to remove 'username' and 'password'!
    # username = None
    # password = None
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    is_owner = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_advisor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    data_join = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    code_agency = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
    # You must remove the 'phone_number' from REQUIRED_FIELDS!
    # Here you can't repeat in the REQUIRED_FIELDS the same field that you put in USERNAME_FIELD, you can add other: 'email', etc ...
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    

    objects = UserCustomManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'
```

In your admin.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


# Here you have to import the User model from your app!
from your_app.models import User


@admin.register(User)
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
        model = User
        list_display = ('phone_number',
                        'email')
        list_filter = ('phone_number',
                        'email')
        search_fields = ('phone_number', )
        ordering = ('phone_number', )
        filter_horizontal = ()
        fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (
                (None, {'fields': ('phone_number',)}),
        )
        # I've added this 'add_fieldset'
        add_fieldsets = (
            (None, {
                'classes': ('wide',),
                'fields': ('phone_number', 'password1', 'password2'),
            }),
    )
```

In the settings.py:

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.User'
# not 'User.User'
```

Comment: my app name is User I think it is ok. but I don't have password field in my model is it true to add in useradmin.fieldset?

Comment: I've updated my answer! Check it out! And I going to be honest: you must add a password in '_createuser'; Why? Simple: if you do not that will happen a TypeError when you try to log in the admin page.

Comment: I've fixed the errors that you could have!

Comment: I got a problem with this when I wanna create a user my user isn't created. it is work just python3 manage.py createsuperuser command.

Answer (score 1):

In your model, remove abstract = True from Meta.
That was my mistake.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
  ...

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("user")
        verbose_name_plural = _("users")
```

Answer (score 0):

yourapp add in INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'users',
]
```